# How do I get SMS messages I've sent?

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I have this Kotlin code. This works but it only returns messages from the recipient. How do I get it to include messages I've sent? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** CommonsWare answered the question. You need to query both `Telephony.Sms.Inbox` and `Telephony.Sms.Inbox.Sent` if you want both received and sent messages. Thank you for the help.

````kotlin
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER)
        val messages = mutableListOf<String>()
        if (cursor != null) {
            val SMSCount = cursor.count
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                for(x in 0.rangeTo(SMSCount)) {
                    try{println("${cursor.getString(3)}: ${cursor.getString(12)}")
                    }
                    catch(e: Exception){
                        break
                    }

                    cursor.moveToNext()
                }```
````

Comment: [Query `Telephony.Sms.Sent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Sent) to get sent messages.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, is there something that I can query that returns both sent and received messages?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You would need to make two separate queries.